# Eclipse 2022-09 (4.25.0) not compiling when save

Tags: java, eclipse, payara

I'm developing a Java EE application with Payara 5.2022.2

When I made a change in a file and I save it in my application. The application is automatically build to the Payara server.

But the change I did in the file aren't propagated. This is still the old version that are lauching in my server.

Do you have any idea which parameters are wrong ? This is absolutly impossible to work now like this. I always need to stop the server and build the application and run it on the server manually.

I'm loosing a lot of time !

**EDIT :**

I have try to start my application with NetBeans and this is exactly the same trouble... I think it has to do something with maven... How do you know if maven is well configured ? Who do the build normaly for a maven project ?

Comment: Are automatic builds enabled? What's doing the building and deploying of the application, Eclipse or separate build tool? How are we to know if you have incorrect parameters when you haven't divulged which ones you're using?

Comment: Yes build automatic is enabled. Eclipse deploy the build. Which parameter you want to know the status?

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with Eclipse. But more with Maven... Something wrong with it.. Very slow and not working well

Comment: Typically, Eclipse picks up configuration from Maven and builds it itself so my guess would not be Maven. Did you start the server in run or in debug mode? Did you try the other? Does that make a difference?

Comment: Hello,
I run in normal mode, also try in debug mode... no difference still very slow and not working when save